# How to reference a window that is already open and call a method from its code behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, non-static

I have a non static class `MainWindow` that contains two non-static methods `ShowAskAQuestionDialog()` and `ShowTechSupportForum()`. I am calling these methods from a different window that opens from an instance of `MainWindow`. How do I use this instance of `MainWindow` to call these two methods? I tried doing this...

```
            MainWindow mainWindow = (MainWindow)this.Owner;
            mainWindow.ShowAskAQuestionDialog();
```

But I guess MainWindow is not actually the owner of the new window that opens from it.

Is there any way to reference that instance of `MainWindow`?

I know I could do something LINQ related like

```
var windows = Application.Current.Windows
                                 .OfType<Window>()
                                 .Where(x => x.GetType() != typeof(MainWindow)
```

But I was hoping there is something like `this.Parent` or `this.Previous`, something where there would be no possibility of also selecting a stray instance of `MainWindow`

Comment: You could create a public property holding an instance of the window, and call your methods using it.

Comment: In order to do it _the way_ you are trying, you simply set the `.Owner` property on the different window.

Comment: I agree with Rodrigo above... it would be the most simple thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **`MainWindow` is your startup window**, you can get it using `Application.Current.MainWindow`.

Since MainWindow will return instance of Window, you need to typecast it back to MainWindow:

```
MainWindow window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a static variable on MainWindow named Instance, set it in the constructor.  Now you have a handle to it.

```
private static MainWindow _instance;

public static Instance
{
   get{  return _instance; }
}
```

In the constructor of MainWindow, add this:

```
_instance = this;
```